# Java check if an image has transparency

Tags: java, graphics, transparency

Is it possible to check if png image has transparency in Java? I need to convert all png images to jpg if png image doesn't contain transparency. Is there method in Java to check this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check if the image's color model includes an alpha channel:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(/* from somewhere */);

if (img.getColorModel().hasAlpha()) {
    // img has alpha channel
} else {
    // no alpha channel
}
```

Note that This code only detects images that have been saved with alpha channel. Images with an alpha channel may still be fully opaque (i.e. alpha = 1 for all pixels).

Comment: @dacwe Nope. A fully opaque color has alpha equal to the maximum, which is 1. A fully transparent color would have alpha = 0.