# Check if an image is all white or fully transparent in Java

Tags: java, image

I was calling a url to get image store locally and it's already working, but I'm just want to make sure if the image all white or fully transparency, so that i can skip the image.

```
URL url = new URL(logoUrl);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
String fileName = logoUrl.substring(logoUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
//call other service to upload image as byte array.
uploadService.writeFile(request, fileName, IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223241/java-check-if-an-image-has-transparency

Comment: Hey guy, as I check it for fully transparency, what about all white color ?

Comment: you loop throw the pixels and check color if all you find a color which is not white then return

Comment: The linked 'check transparency' only determines if an alpha channel is present. There might be no alpha channel but still be entirely white; or there may be an alpha channel that is always entirely opaque. Both of these cases fail the check for 'all white or fully [transparent]'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to check all the pixels to check if your image is all white or all transparent. Use `PixelGrabber` to get all pixels. And if any non fully transparent or non white pixel is found, the image is valid. Here is the code :

```
public static boolean isValid(String imageUrl) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
    //img = img.getScaledInstance(100, -1, Image.SCALE_FAST);
    int w = img.getWidth(null);
    int h = img.getHeight(null);
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
    PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
    pg.grabPixels();
    boolean isValid = false;
    for (int pixel : pixels) {
        Color color = new Color(pixel);
        if (color.getAlpha() == 0 || color.getRGB() != Color.WHITE.getRGB()) {
            isValid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

You should resize your image for performance issues, This way you will not iterate through all the pixels :

```
img = img.getScaledInstance(300, -1, Image.SCALE_FAST);
```

*Note : resizing can miss small area that might contain color other than white color. Thus failing this algorithm. But it will rarely happen*

**Edit :**
Here is the test run for following images :

1. White Image with url  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqRSB.png :
   [image]
   `System.out.println(isValid("https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqRSB.png"));`
   **Output : false**
2. Transparent Image with url https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Wfi.png :
   [image]
   `System.out.println(isValid("https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Wfi.png"));`
   **Output : false**
3. A Valid image with url https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leusd.png :
   [image]
   `System.out.println(isValid("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leusd.png"));`
   **Output : true**

Comment: Thank @afzalex, let's try for now

Comment: I have call a url to get image like code below, and use your function but it's always return  invalid    URL url = new URL("http://us.farrow-ball.com/pws/client/images/catalogue/products/102005/large/102005.jpg");
        Image img = ImageIO.read(url);

Comment: I used `Image img = null` in my code. Which is definitely invalid. I didn't had any image to experiment with. You should provide your image here. Like this : `Image img = ImageIO.read(url)`

Comment: Yes, i'm using the same as your code and here is the white image url: http://us.farrow-ball.com/pws/client/images/catalogue/products/102005/large/102005.jpg%22

Comment: Friend, This url is not directing to any image. It is outputting just text but without any matter.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry that above link have contain  double quote at the end. but I have tried several all white image and mutiple color image, but still get isValid=true

Comment: @fangli Sorry! you were right. Actually I have not tested my code and thought it will be correct. The problem was I used `!= 0` instead of `== 0`. I had to exclude things that are fully transparent. Now I tested my code for fully transparent, fully white, and other images that will be valid.

Comment: I found another issue with this code. The Color constructor that takes a single int argument defaults the alpha to 255 (per the javadoc) so color.getAlpha() will always return 255 for that code.  I think the easiest way to get alpha would be do a bitmask so int alpha = color & 0xff000000; and then using that alpha instead.