# Java ImageIO: check if a PNG with alpha is opaque?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I'm trying to figure out how to detect if a PNG with alpha channel is opaque or not. If it's opaque, all the pixels have a transparency channel at 100%, hence it should be possible to convert to formats like JPEG which doesn't support transparency.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10223941/2041863) shows how to detect alpha channel, but not if the image is opaque.

ImageMagick [can apparently do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34564590/2041863) with `-format %[opaque]`, but i would like to be able to do it in pure Java.

Do you know if it's possible to perform this opaque detection with ImageIO?

Comment: In ImageMagick, I do that by getting the average (mean) value of the alpha channel in the range 0 to 1 (or 0 to 255). If the average is exactly 1 (or equivalently 255), then it is fully opaque. Otherwise, there is some transparency in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thing possible is to use [`BufferedImage#getData`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData()) and brute force going over all the pixels and checking their alpha. If one pixel doesn't have the alpha `1.0`, the image isn't opaque. [Here](https://memorynotfound.com/java-image-transparency-detection-bufferedimage/) you can find a nice example of the *how* but by using `BufferedImage` directly rather than getting a `Raster` first.

```java
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DetectImageTransparency {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

        File pngInput = new File("/tmp/duke.png");
        BufferedImage pngImage = ImageIO.read(pngInput);
        checkTransparency(pngImage);

        File jpgInput = new File("/tmp/duke.jpg");
        BufferedImage jpgImage = ImageIO.read(jpgInput);
        checkTransparency(jpgImage);
    }

    private static void checkTransparency(BufferedImage image){
        if (containsAlphaChannel(image)){
            System.out.println("image contains alpha channel");
        } else {
            System.out.println("image does NOT contain alpha channel");
        }

        if (containsTransparency(image)){
            System.out.println("image contains transparency");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Image does NOT contain transparency");
        }
    }

    private static boolean containsAlphaChannel(BufferedImage image){
        return image.getColorModel().hasAlpha();
    }

    private static boolean containsTransparency(BufferedImage image){
        for (int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++) {
                if (isTransparent(image, j, i)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isTransparent(BufferedImage image, int x, int y ) {
        int pixel = image.getRGB(x,y);
        return (pixel>>24) == 0x00;
    }
}
```

***NOTE:*** This is not my work. I've added the code to make the answer independent of the link. [Here](https://memorynotfound.com/java-image-transparency-detection-bufferedimage/) is the reference to the source.

Comment: I tried the first method you mentioned, but it returns `TRANSLUCENT` while ImageMagick says it's opaque.

Comment: @Gauthier Yes, you are right. I've checked again and the returned value depends on the image format, not on the actual image data. Anyways, I've added a link where it is explained how to go over the pixels and check for transparency.